# SVG path doesnt fit to container viewbox

Tags: html, css, svg

Here I have an icon that comes with a plugin Im using `calender` and a new Icon I want to add to the icons set, the `twitter` icon.

```css
svg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    fill: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" unselectable="on"><path d="M8.1 7v1h2.7v1H8.094v3H11.7v-1H9v-1h2.7V7zM4.5 7v1h.8v3h-.8v1h2.7v-1h-.9V7zM.9 1v14h14.4V1h-1.8v2h-2.7V1H5.4v2H2.7V1zm.9 4h12.6v9H1.8z"></path></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" unselectable="on"><path class="letterB" d="M16.16 4.557c-.883.392-1.832.656-2.828.775 1.017-.609 1.798-1.574 2.165-2.724-.951.564-2.005.974-3.127 1.195-.897-.957-2.178-1.555-3.594-1.555-3.179 0-5.515 2.966-4.797 6.045-4.091-.205-7.719-2.165-10.148-5.144-1.29 2.213-.669 5.108 1.523 6.574-.806-.026-1.566-.247-2.229-.616-.054 2.281 1.581 4.415 3.949 4.89-.693.188-1.452.232-2.224.084.626 1.956 2.444 3.379 4.6 3.419-2.07 1.623-4.678 2.348-7.29 2.04 2.179 1.397 4.768 2.212 7.548 2.212 9.142 0 14.307-7.721 13.995-14.646.962-.695 1.797-1.562 2.457-2.549z"></path></svg>
```

both icons are in svg, but the first one `calendar` is made to work correctly with `viewbox 16 16`....the twitter icon I copied the svg path from an svg icons site....and it doesnt fit the container as in the example...

how do I fix this? I tried using a class to `twitter path` but without success

Comment: for the second icon you need to use a different viewBox. Try `viewBox="-7 0 23 23"`. In order to get the values for the new viewBox you need to use the `getBBox()` method for the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconverted your twitter icon. It was some scale to viewBox issue.

```css
svg {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin: 2px 0;
    fill: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" unselectable="on"><path d="M8.1 7v1h2.7v1H8.094v3H11.7v-1H9v-1h2.7V7zM4.5 7v1h.8v3h-.8v1h2.7v-1h-.9V7zM.9 1v14h14.4V1h-1.8v2h-2.7V1H5.4v2H2.7V1zm.9 4h12.6v9H1.8z"></path></svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16" unselectable="on">
<path d="M16,3.8c-0.6,0.3-1.2,0.4-1.9,0.5c0.7-0.4,1.2-1,1.4-1.8c-0.6,0.4-1.3,0.6-2.1,0.8c-0.6-0.6-1.5-1-2.4-1c-2.1,0-3.7,2-3.2,4 C5.2,6.1,2.7,4.8,1.1,2.8c-0.9,1.5-0.4,3.4,1,4.4c-0.5,0-1-0.2-1.5-0.4c0,1.5,1.1,2.9,2.6,3.3c-0.5,0.1-1,0.2-1.5,0.1 c0.4,1.3,1.6,2.3,3.1,2.3C3.5,13.5,1.7,14,0,13.8c1.5,0.9,3.2,1.5,5,1.5c6.1,0,9.5-5.1,9.3-9.8C15,5,15.6,4.4,16,3.8z"/>
</svg>
```

**UPDATED**

Thanks to [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman)

Individual paths can be edited in: [aydos.com/svgedit](https://aydos.com/svgedit/)

Update: There now is an even better one: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Comment: beautiful!...what did you do? I still need to apply the same size for a new facebook icon I want to add too. this is its path (facebook) `M11.344,5.71c0-0.73,0.074-1.122,1.199-1.122h1.502V1.871h-2.404c-2.886,0-3.903,1.36-3.903,3.646v1.765h-1.8V10h1.8v8.128h3.601V10h2.403l0.32-2.718h-2.724L11.344,5.71z`

Comment: Actually, i opened it in Adobe Illustrator and scale to the right position. Or you can do like @enxaneta said, change viewBox="-7 0 23 23". But the right way will be to reconvert svg to the right scale. You can use any "online svg editor" that you find in Google.

Comment: I need to use the same `viewbox` due to the js plugin. well thank you for having taking the time to edit it on Ilustrator, Ill look for an online svg editor. thank you! +1

Comment: Individual paths can be edittted in: https://aydos.com/svgedit/

Comment: Update: A cooler and better online SVG editor is: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 0):

If reworking `paths` is too much work, you can add a transform on the path

```html
<path transform='scale(.5) translate(8 8)' ..../>
```

or wrap all SVG in a Group with a tranform:

```
<g transform='scale(.5) translate(8 8)'>

.. all paths, rects, whatever

</g>
```